Intellij - trigger indexing after manually creating .idea/libraries/foo.xml
I have a custom project which requires bunch of specific jars to compile. Finding and adding them one by one is somewhat cumbersome which is why i want to write a script that adds them by creating a file for them under .idea/libraries.
Problem is if I create the file myself (or with a script) intellij doesn't index the library and therefore ignores the added library file.
If I add the library via File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add then it all works fine... Is it possible to trigger index when creating a .idea/libraries/foo.xml file manually (from a commandline)?
An example of such .idea/libraries/foo.xml:
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="foo_1.0.0">
    <CLASSES />
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/../lib/foo_1.0.0.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>

I am aware that I could collect all jars in one folder and then add the folder - I would nonetheless like to automate the process with a script, hence my question
I tried searching for triggering intellij index from commandline but couldn't find anything

This is not supported yet, please feel free to file a feature request herehttps://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Have you tried File | Reload All from Disk?

Reload All From Disk doesn't seem to have an effect... i guess it is not supported
